# What is the optimum minimum length for brotli compression?

Tags: brotli, ngx-brotli

google ngx_brotli default at 20

some websites mentioned minimum should be 100

some says don't go over 256 bytes

what's the exact figure actually? both for nginx and for normal brotli compression minimum.

Can anyone help answer? Thanks in advance.

p.s. : By the way I also think the optimum compression level should be 5 and not 6 ... debatable.

Researched online, can't find.

Answer (score 0):

From experiments with nginx and gzip, a minimum length of 4096 gave the best results here.

Benchmarking with brotli and for your specific case (seeing how long it takes until data lands up in the browser) will probably yield the best results.